# serilog write log .netcore

Tags: api, asp.net-core, configure, serilog

I implemented `Serilog` in my project and `Serilog` creates log file but it doesn't write any logs? My `appsettings.json` file is below.

```
{
    "Serilog":{
        "Using":[
            "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile"
        ],
        "MinimumLevel":"Debug",
        "WriteTo":[
        {
            "Name":"File",
            "Args":{
                "path":"C:\\mypro\\ServiceLog.json"
            }
        }
        ],
        "Enrich":[
            "FromLogContext",
            "WithMachineName",
            "WithThreadId"
        ],
        "Properties":{
            "Application":"Sample"
        }
    }
}
```

and my `startup.cs` file looks like in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbmdX.png).

I add some library.

My problem, `Serilog` creates a log file, however never writes logs at debug level.

Comment: I follow this page  **https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration**  and my libs are  serilog.Extensions.Logging, serilog.Setting.configure, serilog.sinks.literate, serilog.sink.rollingfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem. When I add serilog library, VS2017 is added Microsoft logger library so that If you check which  library  is added. It should be Serilog Library.